# Use jquery to replace date format

Tags: jquery

Basically, I want to replace August to AUG, July to JUL, June to JUN...
This is my code below, I tried to use Jquery, and it doesn't work for sure, can anyone help me, please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <p class="post-date">August</p>
            <p class="post-date">July</p>
            <p class="post-date">June</p>
            <script>
                var thisDate = $('.post-date');
                var dateformat = $('.post-date').text();
                switch (dateformat)
                {
                   case 'August': thisDate.text("AUG");
                   break;

                   case 'July': thisDate.text("JUL");
                   break;

                   case 'June': thisDate.text("JUN");
                   break;

                   default:  thisDate.text("JULY");
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: For one, you're not actually loading jQuery. The other problem with this is, that you're using the same class on all 3 elements and using the text() function on the class, meaning that a thisDate.text("test") will make them all look the same

Answer (score -1):

You need to iterate each of the `post-date` and handle each instance separately.

You can use an object to simplify this

```js
var shortMonths = {
  August: "AUG",
  July: "JUL",
  June: "JUN"
}

$('.post-date').text(function(_, month) {
  return shortMonths[month] || "JUL"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="post-date">August</p>
<p class="post-date">July</p>
<p class="post-date">June</p>
```

Comment: charlietfl  i think no need to use hard-coded values to replace. Op have it in the element itself, so just iterate,get first three character, make them uppercase and place it to corresponding element text